# How to solve next js 13 routing reload problem>

Tags: next.js

## Next js 13 Route reload problem

I am using next js 13 app dir. But when i want to navigate to another page its reload full page. When my site is on locahost its working but, when i deploy it on vercel its reload full page like html website.
here is my site url: https://essorybd.vercel.app/

```
<ul className="flex flex-row mt-0 mr-6 text-white space-x-8 text-sm font-medium">
              <li>
                <Link
                  href='/'
                  className="text-white hover:text-black transition-colors font-semibold hover:underline"
                  aria-current="page"
                >
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link href='/mobileaccessories'
                  className="text-white hover:text-black transition-colors font-semibold hover:underline"
                  aria-current="page"
                >
                  Mobile Accessories
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link href='/computeraccessories' className="text-white hover:text-black transition-colors font-semibold hover:underline">
                  Computer Accessoires
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link href='/lifestyle' className="text-white hover:text-black transition-colors font-semibold hover:underline">
                  Lifestyle
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link href='/others' className="text-white font-semibold hover:text-black transition-colors hover:underline">
                  Others
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link href='/dashboard' className="text-white font-semibold hover:text-black transition-colors hover:underline">
                  Dashboard
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it and how did you go about it

Comment: I've just check your hosted app... It works fine as expected.